# Unit test failing 'could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider> '

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, create-react-app

So I have a personal project to practice. It was created with CRA(create react app). I added some simple unit test and were running fine.

Then added some redux logic. But now when I run the unit test it is breaking. **At the moment the application is running properly fine.**

The error message is this:

> FAIL  src/App.test.tsx   ● Console
>
> ```
> console.error
>   Error: Uncaught [Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>]
> ```

According to this error message I went to check and seems fine.

index.tsx

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

My App.tsx

```
import "./App.scss";
import List from "./modules/users/components/list/List";
import Header from "./shared/components/header/Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" data-testid="appComponent">
      <Header dataTestId="headerComponent" />
      <List dataTestId="listComponent" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My package.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.69",
    "axios": "^1.6.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.7",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!axios)/'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

From what I read in other topics this error occurs when I call a dispatch or useSelector at the same level of the Provider. Which I think it is not the case.

What do I need to do to put my unit test working again?

If you need that I add more code samples here tell which please and I update this post

Comment: Can you please add the test code you are testing?